# How can I link an html file to a file in any computer?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu item called "Free Download." I want it to jump to a section on the home page when it is clicked on the menu bar. I have linked this "Free Download" to a file in my computer where it is being locally hosted. My link is the following:

> C:\Users\HEWLETTE\Desktop\freebies\myfreebies\index.html#free-download

However, I want to share my website (file) with a friend and he cannot obviously get the link to work like it works for me because it is locally hosted on my computer and not his. How do I edit this link so that it points to this file on any computer?

Is there like a shortcut I can create?

PS: I've seen things like the "../file-name-etc" type thing, but I can't find something that works, maybe cos I don't know the right question to ask Google? But I'm kinda looking for something like this but I'm a complete newbie and don't know all the terms yet.

Comment: The term you are looking for is `relative` path.

Comment: In your case, `#free-download` should be used, as it links to an anchor in the same file. Also, what you are sharing is not a website, but a page source code. When the page is hosted on a server, it would have the same path for everyone viewing it.

Comment: @vladko312 when I am on the home page, using #free-download works fine. But when I'm clicking it from another page (say, service page), it pops up an error page.

Comment: @ladyem it would be better to host your website in such case. If you really want to do it with files, try `./index.html#free-download` if they are in the same folder

Comment: @c6p Thanks! Can you help me figure the relative path for this file link I have? I'm going to read more carefully through Google answers but it would help to know the new terms mean in relation to my own file link. I am seeing more terms like root directory, current directory, parent, etc.

Comment: @vladko312 Thanks, we're still learning with a friend and that's why we're passing what we've done back and forth remotely when we are not in the same place. Just happened upon that problem in the process and we're trying to figure it out first.

Comment: You can use _github pages_ to host your website. It will also allow you to see the code and edit it on github without sending it every time. Another benefit would be a complete history of _commits_ - all changes made on github, so you will never loose anything.

Comment: @vladko312 It actually works. I will now try to learn more about relative paths (term supplied by @c6p) to see why this works so I can always follow the principle again. Thanks to you both.

Comment: Problem with relative links, they are **relative** to where they are referenced. So it depends on which `html` file the link is. `.` means current directory, and `..` means parent directory. You should construct the path relative to referencing html file.

Comment: @c6p Okay, copy that.